# Failed to sum splited text

Tags: c#

I have a problem when summing all of `bx3.text` to `t2.text`.
first I split `bx3.text` with space

```
    private void total()
    {
        string[] ps = bx3.Text.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None );
        t2.Text = ps.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Sum().ToString();
    }
```

I did try with `t2.text = ps[1]` and the number showed was correct.
but when i try to sum it all, I got error

> "Input string was not in a correct format" on (x =>
>   Convert.ToInt32(x))

bx3.text is full of user-input number separated by single space " "

Comment: It would help if you showed us the content of `bx3.Text` that you're testing against.

Comment: you are not splitting it properly..what are you trying to split!

Comment: bx3.text is full of user-input number separated by single space " "

Comment: @user1784753: Yes, we'd like to see a concrete example of such a string.

Comment: Yes. A concrete example perhaps? Hint: The problem is with your input.

Comment: oh sory all, the text is like "1000 2100 1500 5000"

Comment: I just tested your code, it works fine whenever I input "1000 2100 1500 5000" into bx3, t2 shows 9600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 string output = ps.Select(x =>
                                { 
                                    int myInt = 0;
                                    int.TryParse(x, out myInt);
                                    return myInt;
                                })
                                .Sum().ToString();
```

Above code will sum all integers in ps array and it will omit all non integer values.

First scenario: if x is integer (x=1)

```
  int myInt = 0;
  int.TryParse(x, out myInt); // change value of myInt to 1, because x is integer
  return myInt; // return 1
```

Second scenario: if x is not integer (x="aaa")

```
  int myInt = 0;
  int.TryParse(x, out myInt); // don't change value of myInt, because x is not integer
  return myInt; // return 0
```

If x is not integer function TryParse always set value of myInt to zero ([msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f02979c7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: An explanation that this works because `TryParse` will set `myInt` to zero if the conversion failed should be added to this solution.

Comment: Sorry, now it's wrong. "don't change value of myInt" - that is incorrect. The value of `myInt` is always set by `TryParse`, even when `x` cannot be converted.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I know that TryParse will change to zero if the conversion failed, but when I wrote "don't change value of x", I was focus on value of x, not on what do function TryParse .

Comment: @kmatyaszek: Well, yes, but imagine someone (the OP or someone else) tries to use that explanation and wants `myInt` to have a different value than zero in case the conversion fails. They would change `int myInt = 0;` to e.g. `int myInt = 1;` and have no idea why it doesn't work the way you implicitly described.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Hmmm... Well that makes sense :)

Comment: @kmatyaszek: Thanks; +1 because it's a good solution and explanation now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid characters in your string.
So, if contents of bx3.Text = "1 2 3 4 5", then it will work properly.

Ie,

```
        bx3.Text = "1 2 3 4 5";
        string[] ps = bx3.Text.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None );
        t2.Text = ps.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Sum().ToString();
         Console.WriteLine(t2.Text);
```

will print out `15`.
You can filter out invalid strings by using `TryParse`

Like this:

```
            string bx3 = "1 2 3 4 5abc d e 6";
            string[] ps = bx3.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int a =0;
            Console.WriteLine(ps.Where(x=>Int32.TryParse(x, out a)).Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).Sum().ToString());
```

Will print out `16`

Comment: It should be noted, though, that calling *both* `TryParse` and `Parse` on each number doesn't really make any sense other than forcing something into LINQ which probably doesn't belong there.